# Star Micronics TSP650II bluetooth printer, can't write to EASession.OutputStream

Tags: ios, printing, xamarin.ios, xamarin, eaaccessory

I'm trying to print a label with a Star Micronics TSP650II printer in a monotouch app.

The problem is that `session.OutputStream.HasSpaceAvailable()` always returns false. What am I missing?

the C# code I have goes something like this (cut for simplicity):

```
    var manager = EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager;
            var starPrinter = manager.ConnectedAccessories.FirstOrDefault (p => p.Name.IndexOf ("Star") >= 0); // this does find the EAAccessory correctly

    var session = new EASession (starPrinter, starPrinter.ProtocolStrings [0]); // the second parameter resolves to "jp.star-m.starpro"
    session.OutputStream.Schedule (NSRunLoop.Current, "kCFRunLoopDefaultMode"); 
    session.OutputStream.Open ();

    byte[] toSend = GetInitData(); // this comes from another project where the same printer with ethernet cable was used in a windows environment and worked, not null for sure

   if (session.OutputStream.HasSpaceAvailable()) {
       int bytesWritten = session.OutputStream.Write (toSend, (uint)stillToSend.Length);  
       if (bytesWritten < 0) { 
           Debug.WriteLine ("ERROR WRITING DATA"); 
        } else {
             Debug.WriteLine("Some data written, ignoring the rest, just a test");
        } 
   } else
       Debug.WriteLine ("NO SPACE"); // THIS ALWAYS PRINTS, the output stream is never ready to take any output
```

UPDATE:
I was able to work-around this problem by binding Star Micronics iOS SDK to my project, but that's less than ideal as it adds 700K to the package for something that should work without that binding.

UPDATE 2:
I've been getting requests for the binding code. I still strongly recommend you try to figure out the bluetooth connectivity and not use the binding but for those who are brave enough, [here it is](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyk2xlcyyqhgoxb/StarMicronics%20650II%20BT%20-%20Xamarin%20Binding.zip?dl=0).

Comment: A [similar problem](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2551/easession-outputstream-hasspaceavailable-always-false) was reported on Xamarin's forums. I'd suggest you [submit a bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) to Xamarin.

Comment: Is there a sample (e.g. ObjC) from which you're basing yourself ? According to Apple documentation you might need to set the delegate on the `NSOutputStream` before scheduling it.

Comment: Yes, this code is supposedly working with a Sphero: https://github.com/slodge/BallControl/blob/master/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench/Plugins/Sphero/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sphero.Touch/Tooth/SpheroFinder.cs

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. Any solutions yet?

Comment: @NieldeVries is the problem with a Star printer? I solved it by making a binding to their SDK

Comment: @StenPetrov Sten, would you share the binding code for StarIO library?

Comment: @alexey of course, email me at sten(dot)petrov(at)g mail. Make sure the code above isn't working first, Xamarin supposedly fixed the bug linked to below

Comment: @StenPetrov How to print a pdf by using this SDK..it is really confusing..If you know please guide me..

Comment: You can't directly print a PDF, you'll have to extract the text

Comment: @StenPetrov Sten, do you still have the binding code? Is it possible you could share? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is Kale Evans, Software Integration Engineer at Star Micronics.

Although Apple's EADemo doesn't show this, the following piece of code below is important for printing to EAAccessory.(Note, below code is Objective-C example).

```
    if ([[_session outputStream] hasSpaceAvailable] == NO) 
    { 
   [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]]; 
    }
```

This gives OS time to process all input sources.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can you explain what NSRunLoop part does? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You say `this does find the EAAccessory correctly`

Could this be the reason the `OutputStream` returns false if the session is actually null?

Best Regards,

Star Support

Comment: I would be getting null reference exception if that were the case. The session is not null